# Is it safe to call $(document).ready() from inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I use the `$(document).ready()` handler from within a function, will it still guarantee that the code inside it will only be run if the document is ready, even if the document ready event has occurred well in the past?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

From the jQuery `ready` function [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js).

```
// Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
// browser event has already occurred.
if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
    // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
    return setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is safe. jQuery has several ways to set handlers like this, and the only "unsafe" one is `$(document).bind("ready", handler)`. [From the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> 1. `$(document).ready(handler)`
> 2. `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
> 3. `$(handler)`
>
> There is also `$(document).bind("ready", handler)`. This behaves similarly to the ready method but with one
>   exception: If the ready event has already fired and you try to
>   `.bind("ready")` the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers
>   bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods
>   above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can put it inside a function, and it'll fire whenever you call that function.