# How to replace html href link with button

Tags: javascript, html, button, href

I have a HTML page that has Javascript in it (see below).

Within the HTML page there is a HTML code line that calls a Javascript function.
This works exactly as it should and looks like this :

```
<a href="#" id="hour">hour</a>
```

This code line calls from the last part of the below Javascript.

I wish to replace this code line with a button. How can I do this ?

Thank you

ps the Javascript is for use with dygraph and I did not write it. I know little about Javascript. I'm simply looking to replace the above single line of html with a button that does the same job or produce a button through other minimalistic change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = [ ];
    var base_time = Date.parse("2014/03/05");
    var num = 24 * 0.25 * 365;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        r.push([
            new Date(base_time + i * 3600 * 1000),
            i + 50 * (i % 60),        // line
            i * (num - i) * 4.0 / num  // parabola
        ]);
    }

    var orig_range = [
        r[0][0].valueOf(),
        r[r.length - 1][0].valueOf()
    ];

    // NEW CODE INSERTED -   STARTS
    var one_month_previous = new Date();
    one_month_previous.setMonth(one_month_previous.getMonth() - 1);

    var one_week_previous = new Date();
    one_week_previous.setDate(one_week_previous.getDate()-7);

    var three_days_previous = new Date();
    three_days_previous.setDate(three_days_previous.getDate()-3);

    var one_days_previous = new Date();
    one_days_previous.setDate(one_days_previous.getDate()-1);

    var twelve_hours_previous = new Date();
    twelve_hours_previous.setHours(twelve_hours_previous.getHours() - 12);


    // NEW CODE INSERTED -   ENDS

    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
        "show_csv.php",
        {

            // NEW CODE INSERTED -   STARTS
            //  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(one_month_previous) ,
            //            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

            dateWindow: [
                    Date.parse(one_week_previous),
                    Date.parse(new Date())
            ],

            //  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(three_days_previous) ,
            //            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

            //  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(one_days_previous) ,
            //            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

            //  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(twelve_hours_previous) ,
            //            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

            //  dateWindow: [ Date.parse("2014/03/01 12:00:00"),    
            //            Date.parse("2014/03/31 12:00:00") ],   

            // NEW CODE INSERTED -   ENDS

            title: 'Temperature(&deg;C) vs Time',
            rollPeriod: 1,
            showRoller: true,
            xlabel: 'Time',
            ylabel: 'Temperature (&deg;C)',
            legend: 'always',
            labelsKMB: 'true',
            labelsSeparateLines: 'true',
            colors: [
                "rgb(51,204,204)",
                "#00DD55",
                "rgb(255,100,100)",
                "rgba(50,50,200,0.4)"
            ]
        }
    );


    var desired_range = null;

    function approach_range() {
        if (!desired_range) return;
        // go halfway there
        var range = g.xAxisRange();

        if (Math.abs(desired_range[0] - range[0]) < 60 &&
            Math.abs(desired_range[1] - range[1]) < 60) {
                g.updateOptions({dateWindow: desired_range});
                // (do not set another timeout.)
        } else {
            var new_range;
            new_range = [
                0.5 * (desired_range[0] + range[0]),
                0.5 * (desired_range[1] + range[1])
            ];
            g.updateOptions({dateWindow: new_range});
            animate();
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        setTimeout(approach_range, 50);
    }

    var zoom = function(res) {
        var w = g.xAxisRange();
        desired_range = [ w[0], w[0] + res * 1000 ];
        animate();
    }

    var reset = function() {
        desired_range = orig_range;
        animate();
    }

    var pan = function(dir) {
        var w = g.xAxisRange();
        var scale = w[1] - w[0];
        var amount = scale * 0.25 * dir;
        desired_range = [
            w[0] + amount,
            w[1] + amount
        ];
        animate();
    }

    document.getElementById('hour').onclick = function() { zoom(3600); };
    document.getElementById('day').onclick = function() { zoom(86400); };
    document.getElementById('week').onclick = function() { zoom(604800); };
    document.getElementById('month').onclick = function() { zoom(30 * 86400); };
    document.getElementById('full').onclick = function() { reset(); };
    document.getElementById('left').onclick = function() { pan(-1); };
    document.getElementById('right').onclick = function() { pan(+1); };
});
```

Comment: `<button id="hour">hour</button>`?

Comment: Also, your HTML anchor isn't calling your javascript. Your javascript is bound to the click event of the element with the ID "hour", which is your anchor.

Comment: Don't parse strings with the Date constructor: `var base_time = +(new Date(2014,2,5));`

Comment: @user1062153 Describe "does not work"

Comment: The code for *one_month_previous* will fail at the end of a month that has more days than the previous, e.g. `31-Jul` -> `31-Jun` -> `01-Jul` and `31-Mar` -> `31-Feb` -> `03-Mar` in a non-leap year.

Comment: Still waiting for you to tell us how it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just style it your way now!=)

(IE optimized:)
not sure if this is right tho.

```
<a href="#">
    <button id="hour">Hour</button>
</a>
```

Normal button

```
<button id="hour">Hour</button>
```

form method:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah sorry :D this is Internet explorer optimized. To make it work for IE8 u have to do it like this. sorry

Comment: Im quite sure, u have to -> i have added this in the answer

Comment: Thank you Xatenev. Tried that earliear.

Comment: Thank you guys. The solution was `code`<button id="hour">Hour</button>`code`. No idea why it did not work previously. Perhaps my leaving  `code`<a href="#" id="hour">hour</a>`code` in the line above masked it. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1):

if you want that the link looks like a button, then you can style the link with css that he looks like a button.

http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/01/10/pressed-button-state-with-css3/

Answer (score -2):

Dude encapsulate the javascript inside a function first
    //

```
 function foo()
 {
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var r = [ ];

    var base_time = Date.parse("2014/03/05");

      var num = 24 * 0.25 * 365;
      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        r.push([ new Date(base_time + i * 3600 * 1000),
                 i + 50 * (i % 60),        // line
                 i * (num - i) * 4.0 / num  // parabola
               ]);
      }
      var orig_range = [ r[0][0].valueOf(), r[r.length - 1][0].valueOf() ];

// NEW CODE INSERTED -   STARTS
    var one_month_previous = new Date();
    one_month_previous.setMonth(one_month_previous.getMonth() - 1);

    var one_week_previous = new Date();
    one_week_previous.setDate(one_week_previous.getDate()-7);

    var three_days_previous = new Date();
    three_days_previous.setDate(three_days_previous.getDate()-3);

    var one_days_previous = new Date();
    one_days_previous.setDate(one_days_previous.getDate()-1);

    var twelve_hours_previous = new Date();
    twelve_hours_previous.setHours(twelve_hours_previous.getHours() - 12);
// NEW CODE INSERTED -   ENDS

g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
    "show_csv.php",
    {

// NEW CODE INSERTED -   STARTS

//  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(one_month_previous) ,
//            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

    dateWindow: [ Date.parse(one_week_previous) ,
              Date.parse(new Date()) ],

//  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(three_days_previous) ,
//            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

//  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(one_days_previous) ,
//            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

//  dateWindow: [ Date.parse(twelve_hours_previous) ,
//            Date.parse(new Date()) ],

//  dateWindow: [ Date.parse("2014/03/01 12:00:00"),    
//            Date.parse("2014/03/31 12:00:00") ],   

// NEW CODE INSERTED -   ENDS

      title: 'Temperature(&deg;C) vs Time',
      rollPeriod: 1,
      showRoller: true,
      xlabel: 'Time',
      ylabel: 'Temperature (&deg;C)',
      legend: 'always',
      labelsKMB: 'true',
      labelsSeparateLines: 'true',
      colors: [
        "rgb(51,204,204)",
        "#00DD55",
        "rgb(255,100,100)",
        "rgba(50,50,200,0.4)"]
    }
  );


      var desired_range = null;
      function approach_range() {
        if (!desired_range) return;
        // go halfway there
        var range = g.xAxisRange();
        if (Math.abs(desired_range[0] - range[0]) < 60 &&
            Math.abs(desired_range[1] - range[1]) < 60) {
          g.updateOptions({dateWindow: desired_range});
          // (do not set another timeout.)
        } else {
          var new_range;
          new_range = [0.5 * (desired_range[0] + range[0]),
                       0.5 * (desired_range[1] + range[1])];
          g.updateOptions({dateWindow: new_range});
          animate();
        }
      }
      function animate() {
        setTimeout(approach_range, 50);
      }

      var zoom = function(res) {
        var w = g.xAxisRange();
        desired_range = [ w[0], w[0] + res * 1000 ];
        animate();
      }

      var reset = function() {
        desired_range = orig_range;
        animate();
      }

      var pan = function(dir) {
        var w = g.xAxisRange();
        var scale = w[1] - w[0];
        var amount = scale * 0.25 * dir;
        desired_range = [ w[0] + amount, w[1] + amount ];
        animate();
      }

      document.getElementById('hour').onclick = function() { zoom(3600); };
      document.getElementById('day').onclick = function() { zoom(86400); };
      document.getElementById('week').onclick = function() { zoom(604800); };
      document.getElementById('month').onclick = function() { zoom(30 * 86400); };
      document.getElementById('full').onclick = function() { reset(); };
      document.getElementById('left').onclick = function() { pan(-1); };
      document.getElementById('right').onclick = function() { pan(+1); };
    }
);
}

//]]>  
</script>
```

Now, call the function from the button

```
<button id="hour" onClick="foo()">Hour</button>
```

Edit: And for the document.ready() not being safe:
[Is it safe to call $(document).ready() from inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142404/is-it-safe-to-call-document-ready-from-inside-a-function)

Edit: Guys you are right, and i'm really sorry, I didn't see the whole question before answering.

user1062153 There is no need to do the extra work in javascript, you just have to give the id to the element you are using. Just add the

```
<button id="hour">Hour</button>
```

as Xatenev said. That should work fine..

Comment: @crush This says its okay..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142404/is-it-safe-to-call-document-ready-from-inside-a-function

Comment: Its okay, but honestly - it is not needed and is useless code.

Comment: Thanks kuni. The script is for use with dygraph and I did not write it, and I know little about Javascript and would not know how to encapsulate it within a function. I'm simply looking to replace <a href="#" id="hour">hour</a>  with a button that does the same job or produce a button through other minimalistic change.

Comment: Sure, it's not going to blow up the page. It's completely unnecessary, and this solution would never solve the problem.

Comment: He's got a perfectly functioning binded event hander in his JS, but you're asking him to put an "onclick" tag in his HTML?

Comment: @i-CONICA Not to mention, an invalid attribute. The attribute should be all lowercase: `onclick`. Sure, the browser will cover up this mistake, but it's still not valid.

Comment: @i-CONICA Yeah dude i didn't see the whole code and I just scrolled down and got it.. Sorry for the hastiness

Comment: @kunl The author's code is already contained within an anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready()` putting this inside of another function is just completely unnecessary. It has nothing to do with being safe or not. It's just a waste.

Comment: @crush Yeah i understood that late. In my hastiness, I didn't look at the whole code. Sorry bout that. :(
I struck my answer, so that it's understood to be wrong now